# How much voltage difference will lead to saturation, LM741?

Tags: operational-amplifier

[image]

Which parameter should I look for? I want to know what should be `( Vin+ - Vin- )` to get a saturated output.

Comment: Given that it's a 741, aka the most ancient and unreliable op amp still somehow in common use, the answer is probably pretty close to "any nonzero voltage at all".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

The main one would be the large signal voltage gain. This gives the output in V for a difference in input measured in mV.

You also need to look at the input offset voltage which in this case is 2 to 6 mV. If you take the worst case, 6 mV, and maximum large signal voltage gain of 200 you can see that the output would be saturated without any difference between the inputs.

The 741 is ancient and should only be used to learn about why we don't use them anymore.

Comment: hmm, can you advice me a better one, preferably some I can find easily. What about TL082?

Comment: The TL082 is a dual op-amp from the 1970s. Go to the major suppliers and do a parametric selection which will narrow down your choices.

Comment: should I look for low input offset voltage?

Comment: If that's important for your particular design, then yes. We generally don't use op-amps open-loop. We apply feedback to control the gain and linearise the output.

Comment: So, as far as I understood, input offset voltage should be accounted only if it is planned to amplify a difference like 20-30 uV by a 1000x gain let's say. So with this high input offset voltage of LM741, it will drive output to vcc or vee instead of 20-30 mV as intended.

Comment: Yes, that would be one of the problems you encounter. Others would be noise, thermal drift, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You are to be interested in the large signal voltage gain. Be aware that the specs given are for a very specific set of operating conditions.

Voltage gain is specified as volts of output swing versus corresponding input differential voltage in mV.

Answer (score 1):

Output saturation is defined in datasheet as Vout swing {Min,Max} for Vcc,Vee

If the output swing is say 10V and the gain is 1e6 then input change is 10uV but if the Vio input offset is in mV level, it cannot be predicted nor is it important.

What is important is the Vio Iio specs and requirements for input offset voltage and current and your passive impedance tolerances.

Comment: I probably will have more than 100-200 mV between inverting and non-inverting outputs, so the output is certainly will be vcc or vee, right?

Comment: Why do you doubt yourself?

Comment: the thing about input offset voltage confused me, as far as I understood, it should be accounted only if it is planned to amplify a difference like 20-30 uV by a 1000x gain let's say. So with this high input offset voltage of LM741, it will drive output to vcc or vee instead of 20-30 mV as intended.

Comment: The gain of 1000x does not affect the input offset.  The 741 can modify the Vio with a pot but changing the closed loop gain does not change the input offset, just the Output result.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like  you're more interested in using the op-amp as a comparator. Some more modern op-amps have even more unpleasant behavior than the antediluvian LM741 when you try to use them as comparators. If you need a comparator, a good idea would be to consider a comparator such as an [LM393](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2903-n.pdf). There are many, many better comparators than the LM393 for individual characteristics but few that are as useful, inexpensive and ubiquitous.

It is well specified for the application, such as  response time of 1.3us  typically with a 100mV step and 5mV overdrive. Offset is only +/-2mV max at room temperature and the gain is typically 200,000 (min 50,000).

Op-amps used as comparators can have very long recovery times from saturation as well as slow output slew rate and can conduct large currents between the inputs if there is more than a few hundred mV of differential voltage present.

Occasionally, it is useful to use an op-amp as a comparator, for example if you wanted to compare two voltages that were a few tens of microvolts apart and were not interested in speed of response, though even then it might be better to amplify the difference with an op-amp and then perform a comparison to a reference voltage.

Comment: Nice nice answer.

Comment: Yes, my aim is to use it as a comparator, thanks for the advices!

Comment: I had a quick look to the datasheet of lm393 and it looks like it is supplied by vcc and gnd instead of -vcc. So, I assume I cannot use it to have an output either  +x volts or -x volts. Instead it will be +x volts or 0 volts. Am i correct?

Comment: You can connect the gnd to a negative rail. In fact it is called Vcc- on some manufacturers’ datasheets (ST). You do need a pull-up resistor on the open-collector output, unlike an op-amp. The total supply must be less than 36V so +/-18 or +12/-5 etc is acceptable. Unlike a 741 the input common mode range extends to the negative rail, which is a useful feature.